# Mysql Summary table to keep track of amount of errors throughout the day

Tags: mysql

So i have a mysql table that contains records with ip and error type for that IP.

This table has millions of records every 15 minutes so I need to be able to truncate it before each load. All I need to keep is a running total of how many of each error type per IP throughout the month.

I researched and saw that I need to do a summary table of this but I cannot seem to figure out how to keep a running total of the data after i delete the raw records from the original table.

Let me know if I need to include anything, i'm sure this is an easy request but I'm still newish to mysql. Thank you in advance for all the help!

Comment: You must give some context here, at least a schema example, or you're asking for us to guess what you're doing.

Comment: Read a SQL tutorial about `GROUP BY` and aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(t.ErrorType) as 'ErrorTypesPerIp', t.Ip
FROM TableName as t
-- WHERE Month >= 'last_month_date'
GROUP BY t.Ip
```

Comment: This is the total number of errors per IP, not the count of each error type.

Comment: It should be `Ip, ErrorType, COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY Ip, ErrorType`.

Comment: @Barmar If you read the question carefully: "a running total of how many of each error type per IP"

Comment: That's right. You're not reporting the count of each error type, you're counting all the errors together.

Comment: BTW, `COUNT(t.ErrorType)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`, unless `ErrorType` can be `NULL` (those won't be counted).

Comment: Maybe you meant `COUNT(DISTINCT t.ErrorType)`, which will tell you the number of different error types per IP?

Comment: I think I am reporting the count of each ErrorType!

Comment: No you aren't. You need to group by `ErrorType` to get each error type separate.

Comment: When you do `GROUP BY t.Ip`, you get one row for each IP. How could that report the count of each error type if there's just one row?

Comment: Oh yes, how did i miss that thanks for info. If you want suggest the edit. Because question was for errortype per ip.